# jQuery FullCalendar event drag and drop not working in mobile,tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing webapplication using jsp,servlet,jquery fullcalender.

- It is working smoothly on desktop browser(drag and drop).but testing on android,ipad tab or mobile I am not able to drag and drop event in calender.

  - I just wanted to working(drag and drop using touch) in android/ipad tab or mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its working smoothly using [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)
library ....

Answer (score 1):

I used [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and dayRender to allow selecting a day or multiple days on a touch device. I just added the source and added the addTouch() function from Touch Punch to the rendering of the day cell:

```
dayRender: function( date, cell) {

cell.addTouch();

},
```

This at least lets you select a day or days on a touch device, you may be able to use the other Touch Punch functions elsewhere to do more but I haven't tried it.

---

I am experiencing the same issue with an iPad. I tried https://github.com/jboesch/jQuery-fullCalendar-iPad-drag-drop as well with my fullcalendar application and can drag the one event but can't drag another, it scrolls. I disabled scrolling, but still get the same behavior. I also tried the last option mentioned here https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=724&q=ipad&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars with this project https://github.com/joshgerdes/jquery.ui.touch

I also want to make a selection of days or hours to create an event. I took a look at google's calendar on the iPad, it is also missing this functionality and they have a notification to use the mobile version if its not working on your browser (safari on the iPad). The mobile version does not display any events in the month view so this won't work as an option for my application. A fully functioning fullcalendar with selectability and drag drop would be ideal, but touch devices might not support this well. I'll keep looking for a solution as well, but if google doesn't offer the functionality, it might not be easy to implement and we might need to offer a mobile version and/or live without selectability and drag and drop on touch screens. I'd greatly appreciate anyone else's help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use it (touch punch) in the eventRender function, so the events are draggable, works fine, only 1 issue when you stop dragging on the same day as it was, then the event is 'frozen':

```
$.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;

if ($.support.touch) {  
   $(element).draggable();
}
```